# is regex is allowed in android

Tags: android, regex, google-play

I need to use regex in one of my app ,even i had submitted my app to playstore which is using regex and I had seen one tutorial about regex from a well known tech youtuber and founder of Learn Code Online and he said that regex is not allowed in android app and if the android app devloper should know about these then they will reject your app or removed.

I had already pushed my app updated to play store.

[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykSuHWhh5hc&list=PLRAV69dS1uWTy-hzDNUrq3_mGjvm3ilQK&index=1) is the link of its video at 11:00. Please tell me whether it's  allowed or not.

Comment: `regular expression` are not properly of some language and FYI Android is not a language. So yeah you can use it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he warns against excessive web scraping in android apps. I don't know if this is illegal or may cause troubles in android store.

In general using regex in android apps should be legal and valid, as they're mentioned in the official docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern